# Django no me permite mostrar informacion del usuario actual al momento de crear un PDF

Tags: python, django, pdf

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Esto es lo que muestra normalmente el pdf, pero deberia de ir ahi la informacion de cada usuario, y esta imagen de abajo es la que me imprime cuando uso {% if user.is_authenticated%}{%endif%}[image: ][1]]Buenas tardes programadores, actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual un usuario debera imprimir una pagina de pdf, me gustaria mostrar el nombre de cada usuario en cada pagina, asi se podra saber quien realizo la impresion, quise utilizar {% if user.is_authenticated%} pero no esta funcionando, todo los procesos que se deberian de imprimir en el pdf simplemente no aparecen, se quedan en blanco, he intentado con el LoginRequiredMixins y tampoco me dio resultado, he buscado informacion en internet pero no llego a la solucion, les dejare mi codigo abajo. Muchas gracias de antemano.

## Este es mi html, es la que sera convertida a mi pdf, la informacion que deseo mostrar del usuario esa la que esta dentro de la condicional de autenticacion de usuario.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Receta Medica</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <div class='header'>
                <img style="width: 50px; border: 2px solid red;" src="static/appointments/images/medicallogo.png" alt="">
                <p style="text-align: center; margin: 0px; font-size: 25px;">Receta Medica </p>
                {%if user.is_authenticated%}
                    <p style="text-align: center; margin: 0px; font-size: 14px;">Dr/a: {%user.userregister.nombre%}</p>
                    <p style="text-align: center; margin: 0px; font-size: 14px;">Especialidad: </p>
                    <p style="text-align: center; margin: 0px; font-size: 14px;">Direccion: </p><br>
                {%endif%}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='details'>
            <span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 14px;">Paciente</span>:<span style="font-size: 14px;"> {{consult.paciente.nombres}} {{consult.paciente.apellidos}}</span><br><br>
            <span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 14px;">Identidad</span>:<span style="font-size: 14px;"> {{consult.paciente.codigo}}</span><br><br><br>
            <hr><br>
            <span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 15px; padding: 20px;">Medicamento/s</span>:<span style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 600;">{{consult.medicamento_y_uso|linebreaks}}</span>
            {%if consult.acciones%}<span style="text-decoration: underline; display: inline-block; font-size: 15px;">Acciones</span>:<span style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 600;">{{consult.acciones|linebreaks}}</span><br/>{%endif%}
        </div>
            <p style="text-align:center;">_______________________________</p>
            <p style="text-align:center; position: fixed; margin-bottom: 0px;">Firma</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Este es la vista que me permite crear mi pdf basada en un tabla de la base de datos:

```
class GeneratePdf(DetailView):
        model = Consults
        template_name = 'receipt.html'
        context_object_name = 'consult'

        def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
            pdf = render_to_pdf(self.template_name, context)
            return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

## Dentro del folder de la configuracion para el proyecto tuve que crear el archivo utils.py y este es el codigo dentro de ese archivo.

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

## A continuacion les dejo la url que utilizo para direccionar la vista que genera el pdf con la tabla correspondiente con los datos para renderizar en ese pdf.

```
 <td><div class="delete"><a href="{%url 'appointmentdelete' consult.id %}">Borrar</a></div></td>
```

## Pues pude lograr que imprimiera el usuario actual que estaba realizando la impresion en la etiqueta que contiene el text Dr/a, como se los mostrare en la tercera imagen!

Esto lo logre creando un nuevo campo en mi modelo, pero este no sera mostrado en la plantilla, estara escondido del usuario, solo esta con el fin de lograr lo que estoy buscando, mostrar la informacion de cada usuario en el pdf.

## Modelo, el ultimo campo es el que he agregado!

```
class Consults(models.Model):
    #General Consult Info
    paciente = models.ForeignKey(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Paciente')
    fecha = models.DateField()
    motivo = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
    padecimiento = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
    #Main Patient Info
    presion = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    temperatura = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    peso = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    talla = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    #Any Exams done before
    estudios = models.ImageField(upload_to='studies',blank=True)
    #Interrogatory by System
    digestivo = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    endocrino = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    renal = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    linfativo = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    respiratorio = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    #Physical Exploration
    cabeza = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    torax = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    #Diagnose
    cie_10 = models.ForeignKey(CIE_10,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,blank=True,null=True)
    detalle_de_codigo = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    diagnostico = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    procedimiento = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    analisis = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    #Treatment
    medicamento_y_uso = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    acciones = models.CharField(max_length=600,blank=True,null=True)
    #Usuario
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=None,blank=True,null=True)
```

## En mi vista, al momento de ser creada ese campo esta asignado el valor del usuario actual que esta trabajando o ha ingresado al sistema!

```
class AddAppointmentView(CreateView):
    model = Consults
    form_class = AppointmentForm
    template_name = 'appointments_form.html'
    success_url = '/appointments'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.usuario = self.request.user.nombre
        return super(AddAppointmentView, self).form_valid(form)
```

## En mi plantilla, utilizo el template tag para obtener valores indicados en el formulario como cualquier otro, pero cuando deseo obtener el valor del nombre de ese usuario no me permite, utilizo {{consult.usuario}} para obtener el usuario, y el nombre deberia de obtenerlo utilizando {{consult.usuario.userregister.nombre}}, pero no se me muestra nada en el pdf. Abajo les dejare mi modelo que esta relacionado al modelo de User.

```
<p style="text-align: center; margin: 0px; font-size: 14px;">Dr/a: {{consult.usuario}}</p>
```

## Modelo

```
class UserRegister(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='', blank=False)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='', blank=False)
    correo_electronico = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False,default='')
    especialidad = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='', blank=True)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: El HTML fuera de los `if` si se imprime?

Comment: Es correcto @loki, puedes ver mi pregunta editada, adjunto deje unas imagenes para que puedan entender mejor mi problema.

Comment: Lo mas probable del porque no funciona es porque debes proporcionarle al método `render` el objeto `request`,  de esta manera la plantilla se representa con una solicitud y podrás acceder al usuario autenticado en ese momento, etc. Te recomiendo que la función `render_to_pdf` reciba como parámetro el `request` y representes la plantilla con el, así: `template.render(context_dict, request)`. Y dime si funciona...

Comment: Por otra parte, algo que veo es que la función `render_to_pdf` retorna un objeto `HttpResponse` y luego con otro `HttpResponse` en la vista `GeneratePdf` retornas dicha respuesta, lo cual esta mal y debería dar error o algo así, debes corregir eso tambien.

Comment: Buenas tardes @JulioCesar.. fijate que intente todo lo que tu me dijiste ayer en mi proyecto, y el pdf siguio teniendo el mismo comportamiento, sin embargo me las ingenie de una forma que no creo que sea la correcta pero hasta ahora hace su trabajo, cree un un campo en la form de consultas que no lo muestro en mi plantilla, esta escondido, este contiene la informacion del usuario que esta haciendo la impresion, o sea el usuario actualmente ingresado, perooo, como esta relacion con una llave foranea, no se como extraer la informacion de ese usuario. Su nombre, direccion, etc..

Comment: @JulioCesar realizando template tagging, como lo hago normalmente con los OnetoOneField, he logrado mostrar el usuario impreso en el pdf, pero no la demas informacion, como su nombre, apellido, direccion, etc...

Comment: Lo que deseo hacer es extraer la informacion de un modelo que esta relacionado a User, o sea, seria una relacion en reversa.

Comment: @LuisRodriguez Actualiza tu pregunta y explica tu "solución provisional" al igual que tu inconveniente, para así ayudarte con mayor facilidad.

Comment: @JulioCesar hola Julio, he agregado lo que pude hacer a mi proyecto, espero puedas ayudarme, si necesitas alguna otra informacion me lo haces saber y yo con todo gusto te la brindare!

Comment: El error es porque esto: `{%user.userregister.nombre%}` no es una etiqueta, debería ser así: `{{ user.userregister.nombre }}`, por otra parte todo lo que he dicho que corrigas, no lo has hecho, según veo tu código...

Comment: @JulioCesar oh! ese error lo corregi ayer, lo que agregue fue el codigo que con el que pude lograr imprimir el usuario, el edit de la pregunta comienza desde el titulo 'Pues pude lograr que imprimiera el usuario actual que estaba realizando la impresion en la etiqueta que contiene el text Dr/a, como se los mostrare en la tercera imagen!', ese el codigo que he utilizado para lograr ese cambio, el codigo de arriba no lo cambie, abajo tambien muestro la etiqueta que utilizo la poder mostrar el usuario en la plantilla!

Comment: @JulioCesar por cierto! la forma en la que tu me dices que deberia estar formulada la etiqueta para poder imprimir los datos relaciones a ese usuario, es la forma en la que lo estoy intentando hacer, de la siguiente: '{{consult.usuario.userregister.nombre}}', y no logro imprimir el nombre relacionado a ese usuario!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108660/discussion-between-julio-cesar-and-luis-rodriguez).